# ASP.NET Core View Not Found in a class library (Microsoft.Net.Sdk without .Web)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, csproj

I'd like to have a `Microsoft.Net.Sdk` project that launch a web server using asp.net core. It is a normal dll project, not a `Web` project. The csproj header is the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

And in order to make it work I added (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The web server is launched correctly **but** the Views don't work, I always have the `View Not Found` exception. The views are in the right places and are **Content** file.

If I change from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` everything works fine.

I think I have to add some packages or `FrameworkReference` to my csproj but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you could share how you build you project and which codes you have used for us to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by switching to the recommended SDK tag for ASP.NET Core projects:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Initially I thought that using that mode in a class library project would bring up other issues, but I was only partially right: switching to the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK changes the project output type to `Exe` (not a class library anymore), so it will start complaining about a missing `Main()` method.

But the easy part is that you can override this behaviour by setting the `OutputType` property:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- Explicitely override this setting because Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web sets it to Exe -->
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Moreover, you don't need to include the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework so **you should delete this part**:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```